# After getting json data using Axios, the program cannot read property "TypeError: Cannot read property "

Tags: reactjs, axios, typeerror

I am new to react and axios (around 1 month), the following program is try to get a string in db.json and put it in a component. But somehow, there is a TypeError.

1)Did I miss some basic concept about axios and react?

2)how should I fix the problem?

db.json

```
{
  "listCriteria": {
    "criteriaTitle": "Awaiting Admission: " <---Target
  }
}
```

react.js

```
var [listCriteriaOption, setListCriteriaOption] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/${props.jsonLink.replace(/ /g,"")}`)
        .then(res => {
            setListCriteriaOption(res.data) <-----save the data in listCriteriaOption
            console.log("object")
            console.log(res.data)
            console.log(res.data.listCriteria.criteriaTitle) <----return "Awaiting Admission: "
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error")
            console.log(error)
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])
```

return

```
<Typography variant="h6" color="initial" style={{fontWeight:"bold",textAlign:"center"}}>
                {listCriteriaOption.listCriteria.criteriaTitle} <-----assume return "Awaiting Admission"
</Typography>
```

But end up

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'listCriteria' of undefined
```

Comment: Small tip also, try avoid using `var` as variable declaration if you can. use `const` instead in this case. This way we know that listCriteriaOption will not be mutated in the future for example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You missed one important part, you need to account for the fact that the HTML will render instantly, before you get the response from your api call.
2. You can add a loading state that sets true/false when fetchibng from the api or add a check that `listCriteriaOption` exists before rendering like this:

```html
{listCriteriaOption && <Typography variant="h6" color="initial" style={{fontWeight:"bold",textAlign:"center"}}>
                {listCriteriaOption.listCriteria.criteriaTitle} <-----assume return "Awaiting Admission"
</Typography>}
```

or the loader alternative:

```js
 const [listCriteriaOption, setListCriteriaOption] = useState()
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState()

 useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/${props.jsonLink.replace(/ /g,"")}`)
        .then(res => {
            setListCriteriaOption(res.data)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])


{loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <Typography variant="h6" color="initial" style={{fontWeight:"bold",textAlign:"center"}}>
   {listCriteriaOption.listCriteria.criteriaTitle}
</Typography>}
```

Comment: The code is work! Thank you. 

Is my understanding wrong?

Step:
1) The program call my page
2) axios get the data and put it in "listCriteriaOption"
3) "listCriteriaOption" is undefined since it is undefined in step 1 (previous error step is here)
4) my component part is re-render because "listCriteriaOption" is changed
5) this time "listCriteriaOption" is set in step 2
6) the data is shown

Comment: Yeah, now you get it! I'm glad I could help :)